# HTML 5 supports IIS Smooth Streaming?

Tags: html5-video

Does HTML5 supports IIS Smooth Streaming with all the HTML5 supported browwsers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Microsoft's own readme (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1046/iis-media-services-readme#issues) it would appear that Smooth Streaming is a server-side technology to deliver H.264 video.

Another quick Google query yields this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

Which is a list of which browsers will hypothetically work with it. Nothing like a bit of manual testing to double-check, though ;)